# How to calculate unique rank in SQL Server (without any duplication)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate unique rankings but I get duplicate rankings

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT 
    TG.EMPCODE, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TS.COUNT_DEL DESC, TG.COUNT_TG DESC) AS YOUR_RANK
FROM
    (SELECT 
         EmpCode, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN Tgenerate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_TG 
     FROM 
         TBLTGENERATE1 
     GROUP BY 
         EMPCODE) TG
INNER JOIN  
    (SELECT 
         EMP_CODE, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_DEL 
     FROM 
         TBLSTAT 
     GROUP BY 
         EMP_CODE) TS ON TG.EMPCODE = TS.EMP_CODE;
```

The output I get is like this:

```
EID Rank
---------
102 1
105 2
101 2
103 3
106 4
```

There is same rank for 105 and 101.

How do I calculate unique ranking?

Comment: Since apparently ROW_NUMBER is not returning the correct values can you share what the correct values would be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT TG.EMPCODE, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TS.COUNT_DEL DESC, TG.COUNT_TG DESC) AS YOUR_RANK
```

Ties will then be given sequential rankings.

Comment: This seems like the right solution to me. Curious what is incorrect about the values being returned.